# playing .flv videos in windows store apps

Tags: c#, windows

I am developing a windows store app and I want to play .flv video from url.I used media element control but it is not giving any output.I also tried to load webpage which contain .flv videos in webview but it is not showing the video.I am new to windows store app development.If anyone can suggest something it will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.
the url of video is:http://video.co-learn.in/m1/flvplayer/flvplayer_test1.php?3tcode=3TAE1651&fname=3TAE1651_1L1A.flv&height=400&width=400

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its not possible to play FLV video formats. You need to create your own decoder for it. Have a look at this official Microsoft answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0b1d2d0d-f7ba-4a9e-80bb-d67059453c33/play-mpegflv-files-im-media-element

**UPDATE**

This thread might be useful to you in getting a hint about how to add codec packs in Metro Style app: http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/csharpvb.aspx?ID=054eca2f-4583-483b-8d46-ce7d6214e4f2

Comment: I don't think it supports. Actually the supported formats are those that are playable through default media player of Windows (without any third party codecs). For other formats you need to write your own decoder.

Comment: ok Thanks alot for the answer.Can you suggest something which will help me to create decoder for it.It will of great help.

Comment: I am not so pro in it but I think this link can be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268668/make-mediaelement-support-more-video-codecs

Comment: Thanks for the link.I converted my video into .3gp n tried playing it still it is not able to play.I also tried with Player Framework but it says invalid source.I is able to play .mp4 but not .3gp.Can you help me with this.Thanks in advance

Comment: I've found another link that might be helpful for you. See my updated answer. As I am not familiar with Player Framework, I can't tell you why that error. But as error says `invalid source`, that means the path of the media file you are trying to access is invalid. Try adding complete path like "c:\abc\xyz\pqr\movie.3gp"

Answer (score 2):

FLV is not one of the Supported audio and video formats (Windows Store apps) (Windows)‎ .
 [Your best chance would be to update the URL to provide a supported format.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986969.aspx)

Comment: no, please visit my provided link, it contains all supported formats.