# How to play vp8 encoded data in Universal Windows Platform App?

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, win-universal-app, libvpx

I'm trying to play a VP8 codec video in Windows App. I have completed the Libvpx compilation for Windows as given in [Vpx Building for Windows](https://www.webmproject.org/code/build-prerequisites/). But it does not work for Universal Windows App. It compiles to normal windows (Win32 exe) binary. Samples inside the libvpx library are also not compatible for UWP App. I'm looking for examples in Universal Windows Platform(C++ example would be better).

I have tried to add the 'vpxmt.lib' (created from compiling lipvpx code using Cygwin) into the Universal Windows App project. It returns an error "Could not add reference to "vpxmt.lib" as it is not of a type or version current project can use"

Please suggest if there is another way to play vp8 video in windows (like MediaCodec in Android).
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows 10.

Comment: What do you mean by 'it does not work'? I doubt that it uses any prohibited APIs so it should work fine. Build it as static or shared library using Visual Studio and use from your uwp application.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268668/make-mediaelement-support-more-video-codecs

Comment: You'll have to recompile vpx using UWP toolchain. Then you'll be able to link it in.